# Why does using multiple mutex's on the same condition variable crash this code?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In the code below, which I have tried to make minimially verifiable, runs fine and does what it should (print 1,2,3 in order no matter which order I pass in threads). However, if I change m1 to m2 in the line that I have commented in the function third, this code crashes with the message "terminated without an active exception". Why can't I use the same condition variable to lock on two different mutex's at the same time?

```
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

void printFirst() {
    cout << "1";
}

void printSecond() {
    cout << "2";
}

void printThird() {
    cout << "3";
}
struct test {

    condition_variable c, c2;
    int count = 0;
    mutex m1,m2;

void first(function<void()> printFirst) {
    printFirst();
    count++;
    c.notify_all();
}

void second(function<void()> printSecond) {
    unique_lock<mutex> sL1(m1);
    c.wait(sL1,[&]{return count>=1;});
    printSecond();
    count+=1;
    c.notify_all();
}

void third(function<void()> printThird) {
    unique_lock<mutex> sL2(m1); //If I make m1, m2, this code crashes
    c.wait(sL2,[&]{return count>=2;});
    printThird();
}
};
int main() {
    test t;

    function<void()> printFirstN =[&](){ t.first(printFirst);};
    function<void()> printSecondN=[&](){ t.second(printSecond);};
    function<void()> printThirdN=[&](){ t.third(printThird);};
    std::thread t1(printFirstN);
    std::thread t2( printThirdN);
    std::thread t3( printSecondN);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the crash for a second, if you want 3 threads to run serially, it doesn't make sense to use 2 mutexes in the first place, only 1 mutex. Using 2 mutexes would allow 2 threads to run concurrently, defeating your serialization

Comment: @RemyLebeau Agreed. This is just a toy program designed to highlight the issue I had in a bigger piece of code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it because the C++ standard says you can't.

> 33.5.3 Class condition_variable    [thread.condition.condvar]
>
> void wait(unique_lock& lock);
>
> Requires: lock.owns_lock() is true and lock.mutex() is locked by the
>   calling thread, and either
>
> (9.1)  — no other thread is waiting on this
>   condition_variable object or
>
> (9.2)  — lock.mutex() returns the same
>   value for each of the lock arguments supplied by all concurrently
>   waiting (via wait, wait_for, or wait_until) threads.

The second clause imposes a requirement that all execution threads must have the same mutex locked, if they are also blocking on the condition variable.

(The above is for the `wait` method that takes no additional parameters, the same requirement is repeated for all overloads/variations, including the one that your code uses, which takes a predicate).